# Notation in Perl - what does the ||= operator do?

Tags: perl, notation

I happen to meet a perl code with the following syntax.

```
sub new{
my ($class, $value)=@_;
$lobby ||= bless{
e=>undef;},$class
}
```

what does the syntax `||=` mean?

I failed to google it as a key word, and I could not find similar syntax in the perldoc.

Comment: Google is often not that helpful for random Perl queries (largely because there's so much bad information about Perl out there on the web). You're better off using the Perl documentation web page (http://perldoc.perl.org/) or the Perl search engine (http://perlhacks.com/search/).

Comment: it's also the fact that punctuation is hard to search for in Google!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll find the meaning of operators in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Now what it does: `$lhs ||= $rhs` is equivalent to `$lhs = $lhs || $rhs`. This means that `$rhs` is assigned to `$lhs` if `$lhs` is false in the Perlish sense. This can be if `$lhs` is `undef`, if it is an empty string, a number that is 0.

Comment: In a wider sense, ||= here appears to be initializing a singleton the first time new is called.

Comment: @MortizBunkus it is good, but it appears to be really Perlish false. You said about `undef` and `numeric zero` and `empty string`. All good, i just want to add `"0"` and `empty list`.

Comment: @loldop, Empty lists are never false. Or true. It's impossible to evaluate the truthness of an empty list. Well, that's assuming you're referring to a list value. If you're referring to the stub operator (`()`), then mentioning both it and `undef` is as redundant as mentioning `0` and `0+0`

Answer (score 8):

```
EXPR1 ||= EXPR2;
```

is the same as

```
EXPR1 = EXPR1 || EXPR2;
```

except `EXPR1` is only evaluated once. It's a convenient way of setting a default. For example:

```
sub foo {
   my %args = @_;
   $args{host} ||= "localhost";  # Provide a default host name if none provided.
   ...
}
```

In your case, you appear to have a singleton constructor. The first time `new` it's called, it'll create a new object. On subsequent calls, it'll return the previously created object.

Answer (score 3):

`x ||= y` is the short for `x = x || y`

See the [perlop documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators).

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete this, in non-ancient versions of perl (since 5.10) you can use the **defined-or operator `//`** instead of the truth-or `||`, which has better semantics when using it to set a default value:

```
$foo ||= 42;    # $foo = $foo || 42;
```

for example sets this variable's value to 42 *iff* `$foo` is false in a perlish sense. The problem is, that this operator can't distinguish defined-but-false values from undefined values because both are false.

```
$foo //= 42;    # $foo = $foo // 42;
```

This line sets `$foo`s value *iff* it was undefined before, which is what we want often. It short-cirquits too, exactly like `||`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$x ||= $y;
```

is same as

```
$x = $x || $y;
```